# Tesseract/gImageReader OCR: older texts are missing spaces between words

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm working with some older texts, were the letters are sometimes a little smudgy.

The letters and words get recognized near-perfectly, and when I look at the hOCR or html file, the text looks perfect.

But when I export to PDF with an invisible text layer the spaces between words frequently go missing, for paragraphs at a time. This is annoying when trying to highlight parts of the text and then copy-paste those excerpts.

Any advice?

Other than these old texts, gImageReader is absolutely amazing and does exactly what I want. I did try the "Middle English" language, but that had the same result.

Comment: It will be excellent if you can share some photos where the issues happen. Some times a preprocessing is needed before using tesseract.

Comment: How would I take a photo of that since the issue is with the invisible text layer?

Comment: Tesseract shall recognize the spaces between the text. So is tesseract recognizing the space or not ? if yes than sorry I probably miss understood ur question. if no than post the image of the text here that cause tesseract not to be able to recognize the spaces.

Comment: Tesseract recognizes the spaces, and in the html/hOCR file that you can save from gImageReader the text is mostly fine.
The error seems to occur in the exporting as PDF with invisible text layer. Because then, when you e.g. highlight and copy the text, it no longer has the spaces.